# When deploying a site from custom site template, one lookup column in doclib has empty values for Office 2010 (docx, xlsx, pptx) files

Tags: site-template, lookup-column, office-integration

I'm deploying sites using a custom site template (WSP) that is:

- Saved as WSP from customized Team Site
- Deployed as Farm Solution
- Has lists, libraries with content customized in Visual Studio (elements.xml, schema.xml)
- One particular document library uses at least 2 lookup columns to other lists (other lists and libraries also use similar lookup columns)

In this site template solution, the document library contents are provisioned via a feature.

All of the documents do get populated, but one of the lookups columns are missing values in several of the provisioned document (items).

- All of the documents are provisioned (500)
- All of the columns are populated correctly
- Except for 42 Office 2010 documents  (docx, pptx, xlsx): the "Unit" lookup column is empty (the other lookup columns are fine). This is consistent across site collections, farms (dev, staging, production). Whether 2010 SP1 is installed is irrelevant.

All of the documents with problems are Office 2010. Is there an issue with the `<Property Name="MetaInfo" />` element (in the Value attribute) that clashes with the `<Property Name="Unit" ... />` element? I notice that the Unit metadata doesn't get "attached" to the document (trying to view via "Advanced Properties" --> Custom tab in Office 2010 app).

**EDITED:** Note: I had hand edited the Lookup values `<Property Name="Unit" ... />` element.

Here is an edited XML snippet:

```
<File Url="RFQ Template - Printing.docx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Path="ServiceDocuments_\Files\ServiceDocuments\350RFQTemplate-Printing.docx">  
<Property Name="ContentTypeId" Value="0x010100DC1B6D4D1FF53B4DAF63C4038DA9186B" />
<Property Name="FileLeafRef" Value="RFQ Template - Printing.docx" />  
      <Property Name="Title" Value="RFQ Template" />  
      <Property Name="Category" Value="Forms and Templates" />  
      <Property Name="Unit" Value="11;#Procurement" />  
      <Property Name="ServiceCategory" Value=";#Procurement - Services;#" />  
      <Property Name="TaxCatchAll" Value="" />  
      <Property Name="RelatedService0" Value="93;#Procurement of Printings / Publications" />  
<Property Name="ContentType" Value="Document" />  
      <Property Name="_ModerationStatus" Value="0" />  
<Property Name="FSObjType" Value="0" />
      <Property Name="MetaInfo" Value="394;#vti_parserversion:SR|14.0.0.4762&#xD;&#xA;vti_lmt:SW|Wed, 18 Aug 2010 06:56:16 GMT&#xD;&#xA;Order:DW|98300.0000000000&#xD;&#xA;vti_charset:SR|windows-1252&#xD;&#xA;Category:SW|Forms and Templates&#xD;&#xA;RelatedService0:SW|93;#&#xD;&#xA;URL:SW|&#xD;&#xA;RelatedService:SW|93;#Procurement of Printings / Publications&#xD;&#xA;_dlc_policyId:SW|&#xD;&#xA;vti_filetype:SW|htm&#xD;&#xA;vti_winfileattribs:SW|00000000&#xD;&#xA;xd_Signature:SW|&#xD;&#xA;vti_modifiedby:SR|DOMAIN\\svcsp_adminsp_edited&#xD;&#xA;vti_foldersubfolderitemcount:IR|0&#xD;&#xA;vti_cachedhastheme:BR|false&#xD;&#xA;ServiceCategory:SW|;#Procurement - Services;#&#xD;&#xA;xd_ProgID:SW|&#xD;&#xA;vti_cachedcustomprops:VX|Procurement\\ And\\ Travel\\ Type _dlc_ExpireDate Order TemplateUrl ItemRetentionFormula ContentType Unit Category RelatedService0 URL ContentTypeId _dlc_Exempt vti_title Resource RelatedService ImporteService _SourceUrl _SharedFileIndex TaxCatchAll _dlc_ExpireDateSaved _dlc_policyId Service ServiceLookup xd_Signature IconOverlay ServiceCategory xd_ProgID&#xD;&#xA;vti_lat:SW|Wed, 18 Aug 2010 06:56:16 GMT&#xD;&#xA;vti_ct:SW|Wed, 18 Aug 2010 06:56:11 GMT&#xD;&#xA;vti_cachedtitle:SR|RFQ Template&#xD;&#xA;vti_metatags:VR|HTTP-EQUIV=Content-Type text/html;\\ charset=windows-1252 ProgId Word.Document Generator Microsoft\\ Word\\ 12 Originator Microsoft\\ Word\\ 12&#xD;&#xA;vti_title:SR|RFQ Template&#xD;&#xA;ContentType:SW|Document&#xD;&#xA;Unit:SW|11;#&#xD;&#xA;ContentTypeId:SW|0x010100DC1B6D4D1FF53B4DAF63C4038DA9186B&#xD;&#xA;_dlc_Exempt:SW|&#xD;&#xA;vti_cachedbodystyle:SR|&lt;body lang=EN-US link=blue vlink=purple style='tab-interval:.5in'&gt;&#xD;&#xA;vti_originator:SR|Microsoft Word 12&#xD;&#xA;Resource:SW|&#xD;&#xA;ImporteService:SW|Procurement of Printings / Publications;#88&#xD;&#xA;_SourceUrl:SW|&#xD;&#xA;_SharedFileIndex:SW|&#xD;&#xA;TaxCatchAll:SW|&#xD;&#xA;_dlc_ExpireDateSaved:SW|&#xD;&#xA;Procurement And Travel Type:SW|Related Forms &amp; Templates&#xD;&#xA;_dlc_ExpireDate:SW|&#xD;&#xA;vti_folderitemcount:IR|0&#xD;&#xA;TemplateUrl:SW|&#xD;&#xA;ItemRetentionFormula:SW|&#xD;&#xA;vti_cachedneedsrewrite:BR|false&#xD;&#xA;vti_generator:SR|Microsoft Word 12&#xD;&#xA;Service:SW|123;#Procurement of Printings / Publications&#xD;&#xA;ServiceLookup:SW|88;#&#xD;&#xA;IconOverlay:SW|&#xD;&#xA;" />  
      <Property Name="Order" Value="98300.0000000000" />  
    </File>
```

Comment: It seems that this is related to SharePoint doing document property promotion and demotion - see [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543341.aspx - and the document parser. The Unit (lookup) column seems to be inconsistent somewhere as I had edited the manifest. Does anyone know if the <Property Name="metainfo" ... /> element is required?

Comment: Please **tag by feature or topic** and not by version or product. This helps to attract more attention to your question and keep it relevant. Also be careful to use relevant tags. See [How do I use tags](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264/) for general guidelines. Thanks!

Comment: Just for the record, I believe there can be a connection with the Document Set bug that Furuknap highlighted on YouTube:  
www.youtube.com/watch?v=pYqXdSg75IQ

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked to see if the Unit Lookup column that you are trying to match had its items entered in the exact same order?

I had a similar issue where my lookups all died because the lookup value is not exactly the same.
In your example if Procurement in the lookup list was entered as the 4th in the list it would need to be matched like this:
4;#Procurement

Of course your data has no way of knowing that 4;#Procurement is identical to 11;#Procurement so it leaves them empty.

I wound up having to do some strange math to get my matches to work. I think I did a datasheet view to excel, trimmed off the itme number and then did a copy and paste of the text only to get the data to come over for my lookup columns.

Answer (score 2):

How you create the **Unit** column on the customized Team Site?
If you provision this column declarative you should use **SourceID** property in the field schema

```
 <Field ID="{ID}" Name="Unit" SourceID="DifferetnText" .... />
```

**SourceID** is the important attribute for document property promotion and demotion across site collections.